# Showing well-posedness of PDE by energy estimate

Tags: partial-differential-equations, normed-spaces, linear-pde

I am trying to show that the following pde is well-posed by computing an energy estimate for it by analyzing the time derivative of the $L^{2}$-norm.

$$
\begin{align}
u_{t} &= \alpha u_{xx} + bu,& u(x,0) &= f(x),& u(0,t) &= 0,& u(1,t) + hu_{x}(1,t) &= 0,
\end{align}
$$

where $\alpha$, $b$ and $h$ are real constants and $\alpha, h > 0$.

My attempt:

$$
\begin{align}
&\frac{1}{2}\frac{d}{dt}\vert\vert u(\cdot,t) \vert\vert^{2} = \int_{0}^{1}u(x,t)u_{t}(x,t)dx = \{\text{Use PDE}\} = \int_{0}^{1}u(\alpha u_{xx} + bu)dx =\\[3mm] &\alpha\int_{0}^{1}uu_{xx}dx + b\int_{0}^{1}u^{2}dx = \alpha\int_{0}^{1}uu_{xx}dx + b\vert\vert u(\cdot,t)\vert\vert^{2} = \dots
\end{align}
$$

Where do I go from here? Can I rewrite the product $uu_{xx}$ in some way?

**Edit 1**: I am trying to find an upper bound for $d/dt\;\vert\vert u(\cdot,t)\vert\vert^{2}$.

**Edit 2**: maybe partial integration of $\int uu_{xx}$? Can that help me somehow?

**Edit 3**: by integration by parts of the second term I obtain

$$
\begin{align}
&\alpha\int_{0}^{1}uu_{xx}dx = \alpha[uu_{x}]^{1}_{0} -\alpha\int_{0}^{1}u_{x}u_{x}dx = \alpha[u(1,t)u_{x}(1,t) - u(0,t)u_{x}(0,t)] \\[3mm] &-\alpha\int_{0}^{1}u_{x}^{2}dx = \{\text{Use BC:s}\}= - \alpha hu_{x}^{2}(1,t) - \alpha\int_{0}^{1}u_{x}^{2}dx.
\end{align}
$$

I realize that if all terms are negative, then we have a decreasing time derivative which is what we wanted to show. But if $b>0$ then what can I do in order to establish an energy estimate?

Comment: Integrate by parts and use the boundary conditions of the $uu_{xx}$ term. If $b < 0$, the result follows immediately. Alternatively, you could let $u = e^{-bt} v$ and apply the procedure to the standard heat equation.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @mattos. Can you give me another hint? I have edited my question. I am not sure what you mean by that ansatz, does it become a simple matter to establish an energy estimate?

Comment: From what you have above, you have $$\frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt} \| u(\cdot,t) \|^{2} = - \left[ \alpha h u_{x}^{2}(1,t) + \alpha\int_{0}^{1} u_{x}^{2} - b u^{2} dx \right]$$ If $b < 0$ then the RHS is $\le 0$ because it is a sum and integral of positive terms which is positive. Hence, the gradient of the norm is either strictly decreasing or constant for all time, which means the norm of the solution is bounded above by the norm of the solution at $t = 0$ i.e $$\frac{1}{2} \frac{d}{dt} \| u(\cdot,t) \|^{2} \le 0 \implies \| u(\cdot, t) \|^{2} \le \|u(\cdot,0) \| = \| f(x) \|$$